# Facing error while running Docker on Tensorflow serving image

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I have trained a Tensorflow Object detection model. I am trying to make a REST request using the tensorflow serving image on docker. (following instruction from https://github.com/tensorflow/serving )

```
TESTDATA="$(pwd)/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/"

 docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 \
    -v "$TESTDATA/my_model:/models/work_place_safety" \
     -e MODEL_NAME=work_place_safety \
     tensorflow/serving &
```

## I am facing below error message-

$ C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Mount denied:
The source path "C:/Users/Desktop/models/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/saved_model_work_place_safety;C"
doesn't exist and is not known to Docker.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

I wonder why its including **";C"** at the end of source path and throwing an error.

Any Help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved the issue by adding a `/` before `$` in `Git bash`.

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 \
    -v /$TESTDATA/my_model:/models/my_model \
     -e MODEL_NAME=my_model \
     tensorflow/serving &
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `my_model`. Is it `saved_model_work_place_safety`.

Are you sure that your Saved Objection Detection Model is in the Folder, `saved_model_work_place_safety` and that Folder is in the path, `$(pwd)/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/`?

If it is not inside `testdata`, you should mention the correct path, where `saved_model_work_place_safety` is present.

Folder structure should be something like this =>

`saved_model_work_place_safety` => `00000123` or `1556272508` or `1` => `.pb file` and `Variables` Folder.